# select top 50 records from sql

Tags: php, mysql

i have following database table name tbl_rec

```
             recno   uid   uname   points
             ============================
              1       a     abc      10
              2       b     bac      8
              3       c     cvb      12
              4       d     aty      13
              5       f     cyu      9
              -------------------------
              -------------------------
```

i have about 5000 records in this table.

i want to select first 50 higher points records.

i can't use limit statement as i am already using limit for paging.

Thanks

Comment: I think we would need to know your current query, then. Paging would have a direct impact on what record 'first' refers to (is it 'first' on the first page, or some other page?).

Comment: Do you really need to use pagination to display just 50 records? Usually all these top XX displays on one page.

Answer (score 4):

> i want to select first 50 higher points records.

Then:

```
  SELECT tr.*
    FROM TBL_REC tr
ORDER BY tr.points DESC
   LIMIT 50
```

> i can't use limit statement as i am already using limit for paging.

Then use a subquery:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT tr.*
          FROM TBL_REC tr
      ORDER BY tr.points DESC
         LIMIT 50) x
 LIMIT a, b --for your pagation
```

Comment: Think of this question a little more :)

Answer (score 1):

I am stupid. Didnt get it right at first.
Pagination itself **is** displaying top XX!

Want it pagitnated? All right, order table as you wish and make limit whatever you want. Then paginate until it reach 50, then stop.